# create a non-rectangular UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, quartz-2d

I need to create a view (a uibutton) of strange shape.
Is this possible with quartz2d? i used this code for buil my `UIView` subclass

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // Drawing code
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150, 150);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 200);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50, 150);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);
     CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
     CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

but this is a draw inside a standard `UIView` (rectangular `UIView`)

Comment: Make sure you return NO for the isOpaque method.

Comment: ***paintcode*** is brilliant.  http://www.paintcodeapp.com